# Generate same size image in drawable object

Tags: android

I have a drawable object which contains a app icon and it is stored it in runtime process.when I test it in different screen size it gives me different app icon size .I want my drawable object to give a same constant size of app icon weather it is running in big screen size or small screen size it should give same size app icon.Is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add images for different screen size you can simply following steps:

1. Right clik your on **app>New>Image Asset**
   [image]
2. Select Asset Type: **Image** and browse your logo or image you want to use
   [image]
3. Rename your image
   [image]
4. Click next and finish
   [image]
5. You can find your image in mipmap with images that are for all kind of screen sizes
   [image]