# Android UI Images Sharp Edge

Tags: android, image, imageview

I've been having problems with large images being resized for UI use in Android.
Look at this image, it's an `ImageView`:

[image]
The original image (That arc is a progressbar) is around 10 times bigger than what you see here. In UWP (Windows Platform) we had no problem using a very large image, but here in Android, I beleive it's the Nearest Neighbour method used for fitting images into UI elements, which as you see, causes sharp edges.
Is there any way to switch it into another method? Like Bicubic? It happens in all Android versions I've tested (4.1, 5.0, 6.0).
Just to mention, I'm using Xamarin 4, which I don't beleive as a contributing factor here.
No luck searching through the internet, I'm afraid I'm the only one having this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, you should prefer to use vector image instead of pixel image.

But if you have to use pixel image, maybe you could use BitmapRegionDecoder to decode lines of image and write your own resample algorithm(like Bilinear Interpolation, it's much better than the Near Neighbor) to resize the image, typically in JNI side.

Another possible way is to use "filter" parameter while calling Bitmap.createBitmap method as your original image would not cause OOM issue, just set it to true, it works to reduce the artifacts.

Comment: So, no way to prevent it in design time?

Comment: @AnnaSB UI design time? Try to use vector design tools to make icons, like Sketch, Illustrator, etc. Then you can export suitable size of pixel images as you like, including PNG, JPG, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Vector Images instead of Bitmap Images.

Bitmap x Vector

A bitmap represents an image by a series of colored pixels. Whereas a vector image is represented by geometric shapes (lines, curves) using colors.

The main utility of a vector image is allowing to scale without losing definition.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your reply. I beleive you mean SVG in the first place. That's right, I do use SVG for some icons, but I don't have access to SVG images for everything. For instance, I cannot convert a profile picture uploaded by user to SVG... The main problem here is why Android is using N.N. and how to prevent it.

Comment: For that you can use same image with different size for different screen size like I show here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434285/generate-same-size-image-in-drawable-object/39434410#39434410